# How I enable / disable device dark mode from my React Native App

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How I `enable/disable` `dark mode` hardware button from my `react-native app`. ie I want to enable device darmode from my `react-native` app while clicking a button, is there any solution for this.

I need a solution that applicable in both `Android / iOS`

If you have any idea please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/ this library is helpful.

Comment: On iOS you can't control system light/dark mode from your app; It is under user control.  You could ignore system light/dark mode and provide your own color palette management in your app